# What is the regex for string with the format XYZ%20DEF.emx#ZMP_00234C3B7?XYZ%20DEF/ABC_AL12345?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to find the string of pattern

```
XYZ%20DEF.emx#ZMP_00234C3B7?XYZ%20DEF/ABC_AL12345?
```

inside another string.

Following are the rules for the regex

1. '.emx' is fixed in the same relative position.
2. '#' is fixed in the same relative position.
3. '/' is fixed in the same relative position.
4. all '?' are fixed in the same relative position.
5. The portion before '.emx' is url encoded so there will be %20 in them.
6. The portion before '.emx' repeats itself after the first '?'.

below is the string I have constructed based on the rules shown above.

```
SOMENAME_WITH_%20.emx#SOMETHING_WITH_NUMBERS_AND_ALPHABETS?SOMENAME_WITH_%20/SOME_OTHER_NAME_WITH_%20AL12345?
```

I have made an attempt at getting to the regex I need and below is how far I have got.

```
(\w+)\.emx#\w+\?\1\/\w+AL\d{5}\?
```

This regex finds the string if there are no '%20's in it. I don't know how to modify the above regex to look for %20 within the string.

The regex for finding %20 is

```
 %[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}
```

but I don't know how to combine the 2 regexs to get what I want.

**What is the correct regex for finding the string with the pattern shown above?**

**Based on the answer I chose below I finally use the following regex**

```
([\\w%\\)\\(]+)\\.emx#\\w+\\?\\1\\/([\\w%\\)\\(?-]+)AL\\d{5}\\?")
```

Comment: To combine regexes `foo` and `bar`, simply write `(foo|bar)`. Have you tried applying this to `\w` and `%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}`?

Comment: Why not use `[%\w]+` instead of `\w+`?

Comment: It would be easier if you would show the whole input string and desired output

Comment: `\w` matches just one 'word character' `\w+` matches several. The problem I have is that `%20` may be spread inside the string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
(\\w+%\\w+)\\.emx#[\\w%]+\\?\\1\\/[\\w%]+AL\\d{5}\\?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fM7pU7/4)

Here is example in Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String string = "fregtreDFGDFG5464SOMENAME_WITH_%20.emx#SOMETHING_WITH_NUMBERS_" +
                "AND_ALPHABETS?SOMENAME_WITH_%20/SOME_OTHER_NAME_WITH_%20AL12345?" +
                "SDFSFDSFSDfdste5464565yGFDGdfgdfgdfgdfgTRy45y/retertre?retertreterERter" +
                "45345435XYZ%20DEF.emx#ZMP_00234C3B7?XYZ%20DEF/ABC_AL12345?%?54654DFGDfg?5656//56456";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+%\\w+)\\.emx#[\\w%]+\\?\\1\\/[\\w%]+AL\\d{5}\\?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(string.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

with result:

> SOMENAME_WITH_%20.emx#SOMETHING_WITH_NUMBERS_AND_ALPHABETS?SOMENAME_WITH_%20/SOME_OTHER_NAME_WITH_%20AL12345?
>
> XYZ%20DEF.emx#ZMP_00234C3B7?XYZ%20DEF/ABC_AL12345?

Comment: This is not working in Java. `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(\\w+%\\d{2}\\w+)\\.emx#\\w+\\?\\1\\/\\w+AL\\d{5}\\?/m");`

Comment: @Ajay no, because demo is only to show how it match, you cannot use /(...)/m in Java, use for example  `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+%\\d{2}\\w+)\\.emx#\\w+\\?\\1\\/\\w+AL\\d{5}\\?");` and if you want to use multiline add `Pattern.MULTILINE` or `(?m)`

Comment: marking this as the correct answer because it was the only response and this got me to the correct answer.